# Django-Rest-Framework endpoint not accessing my database collection

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create an API endpoint for my django project. In this project, i have two databases: a SQLite database and a MongoDB database; the data that i'm trying to retrieve is on my Mongo database, on a collection called `tst`.

So on this collection there is already some data. I created the endpoint, then i opened my browser to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/`, expecting to find that data there in json format, but it looks like the endpoint doesn't see any data, although i'm sure it is.

Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my model:

```
class tst(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self): # ALL the signature

        super(tst, self).save(using='dbtwo')
```

Here is my view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('dbtwo').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('id', 'ticker', )
```

And the url:

```
path('tst/', views.tstList.as_view()),
```

I got these two errors on my console:

```
TypeError: Got a `TypeError` when calling `tst.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `tst.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the tstSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

And

```
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

Comment: Do you have any other useful info to share? Other urls.py, errors, what do you see, anything? From what you post apparently, nothing is wrong

Comment: Thought i posted everything, but i just noticed some errors on my console, i'm posting them right now!

Comment: You’re using `Ticker` in you serializes but your field is called `ticker` in your models. Without capital T

Comment: It was a typo error when creating this question! In the code, both of them are lower case, so it's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're only concerned about the `using` keyword argument in the overriden `save` method; you can use wildcard arguments for others e.g.:

```
class tst(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, *args, using=None, **kwargs):
        super(tst, self).save(*args, using='dbtwo', **kwargs)
```

This does not want you to put all other irrelevant arguments in the method signature.

Comment: Hey! Thank you! It seems to have solved the final two errors, but i still can't see the data that is stored on my tst collection of the MongoDB database. If i try to add some data from the browsable api, it will be added, but it's not added in the tst table, this is the weird thing

Comment: @Jack022 That seems to be a different issue, much more aligned with your design. I think you should ask that as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

As you're overriding the `save` method, you need to pass all its signature in order to work. Also, you have to override your `create` method in your serializer.

```py
class tst(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticker = models.FloatField()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False,
             using='dbtwo', update_fields=None):
        super(tst, self).save(force_insert=force_insert,
                              force_update=force_update,
                              using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

```py
class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('id', 'ticker', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return tst.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. I think this solved the first error. Problem is, i keep getting the second one and i still can't see my json data. I'm trying to investigate into this, i think the problem could be in the fact that i'm using two DBs

Comment: Here is what i got: save() got multiple values for keyword argument 'using'

Comment: Here it is: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable